# How to match 2 string lists?

Tags: python

I want to write Python codes to search the matching items from "word" using the "letter" list.
I created 2 lists as follow - word & letter:

```
word = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'potato']
letter = ['how', 'ell', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'tat', 're']
```

What I want to get is the following output as a list, with the mapping result between "word" and "letter" list.
If a complete string is matched, the result will return as "True".
If a partial string is matched, the result will return as "True".
If nil part of the string is matched, the result will return as "False.

```
word_result = ['True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'True']
```

I tried on my own using for loop / if...else / import re, but could not get the result as what I want.

Can anyone give a hand to assist?

Thank you so much!

I tested using the below coding but not work:

```
word = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'potato']
letters = ['ell', 'how', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'tat', 're']

def check_match():

    for l in letters:
        if l in word:
            print(l)

print(check_match())
```

Expect result:

```
word_result = ['True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'True']
```

Comment: Probably you want to use any() method?

Comment: Why do you expect `word_result = ['True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'True']` in the first case? Since the number matches `word` I expect you are looking for partial matches of `word`. 4th word is `you`, which has *partial match* to `how` (they both have an `'o'`). Could you please explain the criterion better?

Comment: @norok2 - I expect to have word_result = ['True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'True'] because:  
hello - match with "ell" -> True,  
how - match with "how" -> True,  
are - match with "re" -> True,  
you - no match -> False,  
potato - match with "tat" -> True

Comment: @EmilyPoon how is `are` matchig `aaa` but `you` not matching `how`?

Comment: @norok2 - "are" should match with "re",  "how" should match with "how". In my case, the desired result will be "wildcard" regardless to any letters before or after the string

Comment: @EmilyPoon so `"are"` would match with `"r"`, but `"r"` would not match `"are"` or is the partial match *symmetric*? Why `"are"` is evaluating to `True` in the second example, since there is no `"re"` there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if your expected output is right.
Here is code that should work:

```
def check_match():
    res = []
    for l in letters:
        for w in word:
            if l in w:
                res.append(True)
                break
        else:
            res.append(False)
    return res
```

output:

```
[True, True, False, False, True]
```

EDIT:
Now I get your question... First of all, you are shown different input:

```
word = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'potato']
letter = ['how', 'ell', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'tat', 're']
```

Then used different:

```
word = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'potato']
letters = ['ell', 'how', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'tat']
```

And the second of all, you want to check if word from `word` has some corresponding letter from `letters`. All you need to do is switch loops:

```
def check_match():
    res = []
    for w in word:
        for l in letters:
            if l in w:
                res.append(True)
                break
        else:
            res.append(False)
    return res
```

output:

```
[True, True, True, False, True]
```

Comment: I tried your solution and I got the following result:
[True, True, False, False, True]

However, the last part of "re" in "letter" cannot match with "are" in "word".
Any clue how to do this?

Comment: Is your input correct then? There is no "re" in 'letters': `letters = ['ell', 'how', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'tat']`

Comment: Awesome! Just tested your solution and it works. Thanks to the support from all of you!

Answer (score 4):

Use list comprehension with `any`:

```
word = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'potato']
letters = ['ell', 'how', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'tat']

def check_match():
    return [any(x in i for x in letters) for i in word]

print(check_match())
```

Output:

```
[True, True, False, False, True]
```

Comment: Expected output is different though.

Comment: I think that the question does not really define *partial match*. You assume that this is captured well by `x in i` condition, which does not match the expected output. I am failing to grasp a *partial match* meaning that would give the expected result in both examples, though.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a precise definition of *partial match*, which makes it difficult to answer your question in full.

However, we can confine this (missing) piece of wisdom into a function:

```
def partial_match(word, letter):
    ...
```

The rest of the logic can be easily written with either a nested loop:

```py
words = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'potato']
letters = ['ell', 'how', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'tat']

results = []
for word in words:
    result = False
    for letter in letters:
        if word == letter or partial_match(word, letter):
            result = True
            break
    results.append(result)
```

The inner part of the loop is a common design pattern in programming, and Python offers a shortcut for this using the `any()` primitive and rewriting the inner loop as a comprehension:

```
results = []
for word in words:
    result = any(
        word == letter or partial_match(word, letter)
        for letter in letters)
    results.append(result)
```

or even more compact, rewriting both loops are comprehensions:

```
results = [
    any(
        word == letter or partial_match(word, letter)
        for letter in letters)
    for word in words]
```

---

Now let us focus to `partial_match()`, if all you want is to make sure that `letter` is contained in `word`, e.g.:

- `partial_match('how', 'ow') == True`
- `partial_match('how', 'ho') == True`
- `partial_match('how', 'o') == True`
- `partial_match('how', 'oww') == False`
- `partial_match('how', 'wow') == False`
- `partial_match('how', 'hoe') == False`
- `partial_match('how', 'xxx') == False`

Then you can simply use:

```
def partial_match(word, letter):
    return letter in word
```

and, noticing that the exact match (described by `word == letter`) will also satisfy the `partial_match()` you end up @U10-Forward's answer by omitting the `==` check, inlining `partial_match()` and a couple of renames.

If your `partial_match()` should be different, all of the above is still valid, and you just need to refine that function.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't make it clear enough for the question that I asked and caused confusion to you.....Your answer is very clear and comprehensive which is very useful for future reference, thank you for your help!!